# How to get Date & Time using onEdit(e) function for multipal Sub Sheets in Google Spread Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A Google Sheet with Multiple Sub-Sheets for each user. Each user is doing the entry and I need to calculate performance based on data entry date/time. I use following onEdit(e) function it works fine for 1 Sheet... But when I make multiple copies of same script for other Sub-Sheets... It Stops Working.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
      watchcols = [2],
      offsetcols = [-1],
      ind = watchcols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
  if (s.getName() !== "Sheet1" || ind === -1) return ;
  e.range.offset(0,offsetcols[ind])
  .setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS"))
}
```

Can someone please figure help me on this one?

**Thank you in advance for reading my post and helping me out!**

Comment: Could you be specific what are the 'multiple copies' you made? It should work for other sheets if you simply add the conditions `s.getName() == 'Other sheet'`

Comment: I think we can only use 1 onEdit function at a time in Google Sheet... as i have different sub-sheets, it dont work for 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: You function should handle all sheets in your spreadsheet

Comment: How? Other sheets have different columns when edit i get time & date stamp...

Comment: Put the criteria in the scope of each condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE - using Utilities.formatDate(date, time zone, format) with local time zone.  Find your [local time zone id from here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#timezone-ids)

What about separating the function from onEdit():

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
    
   if (e.value){
      if (s.getName() === "AAA" && col === 4) { setDateTime(range, -3)};
      if (s.getName() === "BBB" && col === 6) { setDateTime(range, -5)};
      if (s.getName() === "CCC" && col === 10) { setDateTime(range, -6)};   
   }
}
    
    
function setDateTime(range, offsetcols){
  var date =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"America/New_York", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  
  Logger.log(date);
       
  range.offset(0,offsetcols).setValue(date);
}
```

Comment: Its working, but not showing accurate time. What's the solution for getting accurate timing? i.e. Its 4:32 PM here in Miami... But data entry time is showing 01:46 AM time...
Spread sheet time settings are set to United States... -5 GMT Eastern Timing.

Comment: Also, its very slow... why is that?

Comment: App Script server defaults to US Pacific Time Zone - so to specify a time zone, use Utilities.formatDate(date, 'America/New_York' , "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS"); and replace the second parameter with your time zone.  

Here is a list of timezones: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#timezone-ids

Comment: As for the speed, without seeing the sheet and usage of the code, I just worked off of @idfurw code.  You will have to fine tune it.

Comment: Utilities.formatDate(date, 'America/New_York' , "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS");

Tried using this, but not working at all.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tjLgryT_eaHGopJinbEn3xOqRHlqfCeZ1aHAXUDcMM/edit?usp=sharing

I created a Sample google sheet with same code... Please have a look and let me know if this can be fixed please? 

I need this done Badly!!!

Comment: But Time difference is not coming at its actual...
i tried doing 3 entries... after 2 seconds each.. and here are results...

Actual Data Entry Time: 8/18/2021 17:24:12 Time Stamp: 8/18/2021 17:28:46
Actual Data Entry Time: 8/18/2021 17:24:14 Time Stamp: 8/18/2021 17:37:49
Actual Data Entry Time: 8/18/2021 17:24:16 Time Stamp: 8/18/2021 17:36:12

Comment: I updated the code above.   There were two problems, 1) you can only have 1 onEdit() in your code, but you had one in Code.gs and another in CODE1.gs.   The files are only to help people group code, the server sees it all as one thing.    2) The date format was causing problems, the SS is fractions of a second, which Google Sheets reformatted, causing the strange behavior.   I updated that as well.   Lastly, I reduced the complexity of the code.  Should run faster now.

Comment: I have a problem again, if User type something time/date is coming... But if User is Dragging Data from Above Rows to Down... It don't show any date/time, can you please help?

Comment: I believe, and hopefully someone can clarify, onEdit() only triggers if the contents of a cell change.   If someone moves a cell, the contents didn't change, just the location, so I don't think onEdit() will be triggered.  You may need to set up an installable trigger, such as onChange(), but I have not worked with that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
      watchcols = [2],
      offsetcols = [-1],
      ind = watchcols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
  if (ind === -1) return ;
  if (s.getName() === "Sheet1") {
    e.range.offset(0,offsetcols[ind])
    .setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS"))
  }

  else if (s.getName() === "Sheet2") {
  }

  else if (s.getName() === "Sheet3") {
  }
}
```

Comment: But Sheet2 and Sheet3 have different columns where they edit and i get time stamps... i.e. For Sheet2 is... 
watchcols = [3],
offsetcols = [-2],

and for Sheet3 its
watchcols = [5],
offsetcols = [-4],

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1',"add others"]
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  const watchcols = [2];
  const offsetcols = [-1];
  const ind = watchcols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if (~idx && ~ind) {
    e.range.offset(0,offsetcols[ind]).setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper Its working in All Sheets... But I need separate columns to be edited/updated with timestamp in each sheet... what's for that?